Proving the natural transformation $\eta \colon F \Rightarrow G$
Definitions
Let $\mathcal{C} := (\mathbb{R}, f_{\_,\_})$ be the category where the objects are the real numbers and the morphisms $f_{\_,\_}$ are given by the " $\_$ less than or equal to $\_$" relation.
In other words, every object is a real number $x$, and for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$f_{x,y} \colon \,\ x \to y \,\ \stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} x \leq y.$$
Define $\mathcal{D} := \mathcal{C}^{\mathbf{op}}$, where the objects are the same as $\mathcal{C}$, but the morphisms are $f_{x,y}^{\mathbf{op}} := f_{y,x}$.
The identity is $\operatorname{id}_x := f_{x,x} = f_{x,x}^{\mathbf{op}}$.
Let $g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be any strictly decreasing function such that $g(x) \leq -x$ for all real numbers $x$. Define the functors $F,G \colon \,\ \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$, such that $F(x) =-x$ and $G(x) = g(x)$ and $F(f_{x,y}) = f_{-y, -x}$ and $G(f_{x,y}) = f_{g(y), g(x)}$.
Question
How can I prove that $\eta \colon \,\ F \Rightarrow G$ defined by the morphism $\eta \colon F(\_) \to G(\_)$ is a natural transformation?
My attempt is the following. Given this diagram:

I want to show that $\eta_y \circ f_{-y,-x} = f_{g(y),g(x)} \circ \eta_x$.
Let $f_{x,y} \colon x \to y$ be any morphism in $\mathcal{C}$. Assume $x \leq y$. Send $x$ to $g(x)$ and compare it to $g(y)$ with $g(y) \leq g(x) \leq -x$. Hence $g(y) \leq -x$. Also, if we compare $-x$ and $-y$ with $-y \leq -x$ and then send $-y$ to $g(y)$, we'll have $g(y) \leq -x$. Hence, $\eta \colon F \Rightarrow G$ is a natural transformation.
Is this analogy correct?
Bonus question: Is it a natural isomorphism?

Yes, this is indeed correct; in fact, all you need to show is that the maps exist, and commutativity follows trivially since the category you are considering is a preorder: that is, there can only exist one morphism between two objects. It need not be a natural isomorphism though, as this requires g(x)=-x. You can check it yourself :)

Thank you so much! I understood now!

Clarifying the definitions:
For category $\mathcal{C}$:

$Ob(\mathcal{C}) = \mathbb{R}$
For $X, Y \in Ob(\mathcal{C})$, $Hom(X, Y) = \{\; (a, b) \in (\mathbb{R}, \leq) \;| \; a = X, \; b = Y \;\}$.

$\mathcal{C}$ is ‘thin’, meaning it only has at most one morphism between any two objects. I think you could call this “the poset category on $\mathbb{R}$”, amongst other things.



For category $\mathcal{D}$:

Category $\mathcal{D} := \mathcal{C}^{op}$.

This means that $Ob(\mathcal{D}) = Ob(\mathcal{C})$, and for $X, Y \in Ob(\mathcal{D})$, $Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(X, Y) = Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(Y, X)$.

For example, because $0, 3 \in \mathbb{R}$, $Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(0, 3)$ exists, and is equal to $Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(3,0)$, which equals $\emptyset$, because there are no elements $(a, b)$ in the relation $(\mathbb{R}, \leq)$ such that $a = 3$ and $b = 0$.
And because $-1 \in \mathbb{R}$, $Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(0, -1)$ exists, and is equal to $Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(-1, 0) = \{(-1, 0)\}$.
We could prove that $\mathcal{D}$ is equivalent to the poset category defined by $(\mathbb{R}, \geq)$.





For functor $\mathcal{F}$:

Consider a function $f_0: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $f_0(x) = -x$.

I believe we could say that this “induces” a functor, but I’m not
sure right now how to show that formally.


Suffice it to say, if we also have a function $f_1 :
Arr(\mathcal{C}) \to Arr(\mathcal{D})$ (where $Arr()$ is the
collection of Hom-sets in a category) such that for
$Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(A, B) \in Arr(\mathcal{C})$,
$f_1(Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(A, B)) = Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(-B, -A)$, we can
argue that these maps form a functor $\mathcal{F}: \mathcal{C} \to
\mathcal{D}$, by checking the functor axioms - that composition of
morphisms commutes with the functor, and identities are preserved.

I am pretty sure this is an automorphism on the relation $(\mathbb{R}, \leq)$, which could be proven.



For functor $\mathcal{G}$:
I am pretty sure this is actually a family of functors, where each one is defined in terms of a function $g_i: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, for which $g_i(x) \leq -x$. If we map the objects of $\mathcal{C}$ using $g_i(X)$, and the Hom-sets with $Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(A, B) = Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(g_i(A), g_i(B))$, I assume similarly we can prove that this acts as a functor and fulfills the functor axioms. Another thing to think about is that $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are contravariant endofunctors.
Now, I want to improve and finish this answer, but it took me forever to type out the above, so I’ll come back later. I’m also studying category theory and I would like to give an answer which can answer the question using the formalisms of category theory. Thank you.
